# Deploy rsa key to other machines

Tags: linux, centos, ansible, centos7

I am trying to create a key in one host and then deploy the key in the remaining hosts.
But ansible is erroring out because its not able to find my key.

I have created the user dbadmin and later i am trying to push the key, What could be the error. Verbose does not help much unfortunately.

```
 - name: Create user
    user:
       name: dbadmin
       shell: /bin/bash

  - name: Add user to sudoers group
    copy:
          dest: "/etc/sudoers.d/dbadmin"
          content: "devops  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL"

  - name: Give ssh directory readable
    file:
        path: /home/dbadmin/.ssh
        owner: dbadmin
        group: dbadmin
        mode: 0700
        state: directory

  - name: Generate /etc/ssh RSA host key
    command: su dbadmin -c 'ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -f /home/dbadmin/.ssh/vid_rsa -N ""'
    args:
      creates: /home/dbadmin/.ssh/vid_rsa
    run_once: True


  - name: Disable Password Authentication
    lineinfile:
           dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
           regexp='^PasswordAuthentication'
           line="PasswordAuthentication no"
           state=present
           backup=yes

  - name: Disable Password Authentication
    lineinfile:
        dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        regexp: '^PermitRootLogin '
        line: PermitRootLogin no"
        state: present
        backup: yes

  - name: Deploy ssh key
    authorized_key:
        user: dbadmin
        key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/dbadmin/.ssh/vid_rsa.pub') }}"
        path: '/home/dbadmin/.ssh'
```

ERROR:

```
TASK [vertica-backup-restore : Deploy ssh key] *****************************************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/dbadmin/.ssh/vid_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

fatal: [xx.xxx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/dbadmin/.ssh/vid_rsa.pub"}
 [WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/dbadmin/.ssh/vid_rsa.pub' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

[dbadmin@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ssh]$ ls -al
total 8
drwx------ 2 dbadmin dbadmin   40 Apr  9 12:48 .
drwx------ 3 dbadmin dbadmin   74 Apr  8 22:41 ..
-rw------- 1 dbadmin dbadmin 1675 Apr  9 12:48 vid_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 dbadmin dbadmin  417 Apr  9 12:48 vid_rsa.pub
[dbadmin@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.ssh]$ pwd
/home/dbadmin/.ssh
```

Comment: Try to use existing Ansible solutions instead of handling everything with the shell. For example, instead of `command: su dbadmin -c 'ssh-keygen...`, use `become_user: dbadmin` and `command: ssh-keygen...` (I don't think that is *the* problem, but it thins the smoke a little...)

Answer (score 0):

From the code given, it is not clear to me how exactly should this copy a key from one host to some others, but I am going to guess that you create the user and the key pair respectively on a remote machine.

Since the `authorized_key` module will most likely look for the file on your control machine (the one running ansible), if you ran the tasks on a remote server, it won't be able to find the key locally.

In order to solve this you can use: `delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"`, but in order to copy a key from one host to the others, you will still have to iterate that task over all your desired hosts, and delegate it to the host you created the user on.

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) to better understand delegation.

If this was not the issue, it might help if you update the question with the hosts (not real IP addresses) so we can see what might go wrong there.